# Retrieve rows from Monday to Friday in Django?

Tags: python, django

This is my model:

```
class SilverPriceManager(models.Manager):
    def missing_working_days(self, currency, year):
        if currency == 'usd':
            return self.filter(usd__isnull=False, date__year=year)
        else:
            return None

class SilverPrice(models.Model):
    date   = models.DateField(unique=True, help_text='Date for silver price.')
    usd    = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=15, decimal_places=10, help_text='USD price.')
    gbp    = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=15, decimal_places=10, help_text='GBP price.')
    eur    = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=15, decimal_places=10, help_text='EUR price.')

    objects = SilverPriceManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

I am trying to select all rows whose dates that are from Monday to Friday.
Is there some easy django specific trick ?

I already have some code in my manager, but it is selecting all days.

Comment: For the record: unfrotunatelly you can't do `date__week_day__in=[…]`, so in this particular case its probably easier to exclude weekends. Related ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10911

Comment: This is selecting Moday self.filter(usd__isnull=True, date__week_day=2 ), but how to select Monday to Friday ?

Comment: Try reading my previous comment.

Comment: I did, but with no success, from ticket I do not understand is this feature even implemented ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django has [`week_day` lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#week-day) but unfortunatelly you [can't use lookup operators on it](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10911). Once this feature is implemented you'll be able to do:

```
SilverPrice.objects.filter(date__week_day__range=(2,6))
```

But for now this won't work and your only option is a chain of filters. I think the easiest way to do that is excluding weekends:

```
SilverPrice.objects.exclude(date__week_day=1).exclude(date__week_day=7)
```

Comment: would this not work too `SilverPrice.objects.filter(date__week_day__in = range(2,5))` ? I guess it should.

Comment: @karthikr It won't precisely for the same reason.

Comment: I hadnt read the link. may be spoke too soon.. Good answer